# How to add jQuery script?

Tags: jquery

I want to add small jQuery script in my WordPress how to do that?

Here's the JQuery script that I want to add:

```
  ( function( window ) {
   'use strict';

  function classReg( className ) {
   return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
  }
   var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

   if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
    hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
     return elem.classList.contains( c );
   };
   addClass = function( elem, c ) {
   elem.classList.add( c );
  };
   removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
 }
   else {
   hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
   return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
 };
 addClass = function( elem, c ) {
   if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
   elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
  }
 };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
 elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
 };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
 fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  define( classie );
} else {
 window.classie = classie;
 }

})( window );

var $ = function(selector){
return document.querySelector(selector);
}
var accordion = $('.accordion');

accordion.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
 if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") {
  var classes = e.target.className.split(" ");
   if(classes) {
  for(var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
    if(classes[x] == "accordionTitle") {
      var title = e.target;

      var content = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;

      classie.toggle(title, 'accordionTitleActive');

      if(classie.has(content, 'accordionItemCollapsed')) {
        if(classie.has(content, 'animateOut')){
          classie.remove(content, 'animateOut');
        }
        classie.add(content, 'animateIn');

      }else{
         classie.remove(content, 'animateIn');
         classie.add(content, 'animateOut');
      }

      classie.toggle(content, 'accordionItemCollapsed');

      }
     }
    }
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to add a inline script that depends on jQuery, the best and correct way is to use `wp_enqeue_scripts` action hook, or `wp_footer`, depends on the situation, combined with `wp_script_is()` function:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cyb_print_inline_script' );
function cyb_print_inline_script() {
  //Check that jQuery has been printed
  if ( wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) {
    ?>
    <script>
        // js code goes here
    </script>
    <?php
  }
}
```

But you can end up with issues because you are not managing depdencies correctly. The really correct way is to **not print inline scripts that has dependencies**. Instead, enqueue it in a file.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cyb_enqueue_scripts' );
function cyb_enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        //Name to handle your script
        'my-script-handle',
         //URL to the script file
         get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my-script.js',
         //Set the dependencies
         array( 'jquery' ),
         //Version
         '1.0',
         //In footer: true to print the script in footer, false to print it on head
         true
    );

}
```

If you need to pass variables to your script, use [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) as follow:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqeue_scripts', 'cyb_enqueue_scripts' );
function cyb_enqueue_scripts() {

   //Register the js file
    wp_register_script(
        //Name to handle your script
        'my-script-handle',
         //URL to the script file
         get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my-script.js',
         //Set the dependencies
         array( 'jquery' ),
         //Version
         '1.0',
         //In footer: true to print the script in footer, false to print it on head
         true
    );


    //Localize the needed variables
    $script_vars = array(
        'some_var' => 'some value',
        'another_var' => 'another value'
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'my-script-handle', 'object_name_passed_to_script', $script_vars );

    //Enqueue the script
    wp_enqueue_script('my-script-handle');

}
```

Comment: I follow your instructions but after I edit and reload my website, I'm getting white blank page

Comment: Which one of the options I proposed you have tried? There was a missing "u" in the function name of the second block of code. Other than that, I don't find any error in the code.

Comment: I try the second one

Comment: The function name error is fixed. Try again.

Comment: I try it, but the script is not working in my wordpress. here's must be the output of that js http://codepen.io/chriswrightdesign/pen/cmanI

Comment: Check that the path to the js file is correct. In the answer I use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my-script.js'` but it is just an example that, obviously, you have to change to match the actual path to the file. And please, when say "it doesn't work" you are providing no useful information, try to provide some debug information that allow us tho help you better.

Comment: The path is correct, i changed also the stylesheet into this get_template_directory_uri() but the js is still not running

Comment: `get_template_directory_uri()` and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` return the same if no child theme is used (if child theme is used, `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` returns URL to child theme directory while `get_template_directory_uri()` returns URL to parent theme directory). Anyway, if the file is **correctly loaded** (check that) and it is not working.....that is another problem out of the scope of this site. I can not help you in that as it is not related with WordPress but with a third party software.

Answer (score -1):

You can add them into functions.php file, code below:

```
    //load js

    function load_js(){
        if(is_page(Page ID, Page Title or Page Slug)){
        //put your js code here
        }
    }

    add_action('wp_footer', 'load_js', 20); //for footer   
    add_action('wp_head', 'load_js', 8); //for head
```

or:

```
function load_js(){
  if(is_page(19)){
     wp_enqueue_script('UniqueName', 'jsfilepath', false, 'version number', true ); // the last parameter true for footer false for head
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js')
```

Code have been tested. It's OK!

Comment: How about I want to use jQuery in specific pages only?

Comment: Syntax is not right and will lead to errors.

Comment: I have corrected the code. Now it's Ok!